# Friendly URL does not work with HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https

- if I open link http://www.example.com/friednly-url/ **it works**.
- if I open link https://www.example.com/friednly-url/ **it throws 404
  error.**
- if I open link https://www.example.com/file.php **it works**.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Rewriterule  ^(friendly-url)  index.php?file=first&cat_id=0,01
```

Did i missed something? I have no idea, why i can't open friendly Url with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I just forgot to add some options to virtualhost file: `<virtualhost *:433>` file:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```